# Update causing data lost / deleted

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I am using .Net Core 3.1, I tried to update data that retrieved with lazy loading.

```
    [HttpPost("update")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody] FooDto fooDto){
        var foo = await _context.Foo
        .Include( x => x.Bar)
        .Where(x => x.Id == fooDto.Id).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
        if(foo == null)
            return BadRequest("Foo not found");
        _mapper.Map<FooDto, Foo>(fooDto, foo);
        if(await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0){
            fooDto = _mapper.Map<Foo, FooDto>(foo);
            return Ok(fooDto);
        }
        throw new Exception("Cannot update Foo");
    }
```

FooDto itself:
    public class FooDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FooName { get; set; }
        public int BarId { get; set; }
        public BarDto Bar { get; set; }
    }

I send this data from Postman to test:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "fooName": "fooUpdate1",
    "barId": 1
}
```

and boom .. the data was deleted from my database. No error were produced. 
I was wonder why this is happening.

But if I tried

```
var foo = await _context.Foo
            .Where(x => x.Id == fooDto.Id).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

It will work well and updated the record. Is this bug on EF core / Mysql Pomelo ? or I dont need to retrieve data with lazy loading one in order to do update ?

note: I use .Net Core 3.1, AutoMapper 9, Pomelo Mysql 3.1 and EF Core 3.1.1

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.1" />    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.1.1" />  
</ItemGroup>
```

my full code: 
https://pastebin.com/ck1gCtd8

Comment: Does code work with Core 2.0?  I've seen a number of postings where 2.0 works and 3.1 does not work.

Comment: It seems it work on 2.0, i also upgraded this from 2 to 3.

Comment: It is not your code, it is Core 3.1.